# COM out-ptr remains null in client

Tags: c++, windows, com

What would cause an [IEnumString->Next()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693735.aspx) call to call the correct function but leave the client's pointer null? Everything is 64bit (Windows 10).

Data flow: My DLL -> [MSSpellCheckingHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869852.aspx) -> Client

[In my code (Github link)](https://github.com/TinoDidriksen/spellers/tree/master/windows/win8) everything checks out. The allocation and copy look fine. But the client sees a null pointer, but only when coming via [ISpellCheckProvider->Suggest();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869788.aspx) it works fine via [ISpellCheckProviderFactory->get_SupportedLanguages()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869793.aspx)

Snippet from [EnumString.hpp](https://github.com/TinoDidriksen/spellers/blob/master/windows/win8/EnumString.hpp) :

```
template<typename String>
inline void CoCopyWString(const String& in, PWSTR* out) {
    debugp p(__FUNCTION__);
    p(in, static_cast<void*>(*out));
    *out = reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*(in.size() + 1)));
    std::copy(in.begin(), in.end(), *out);
    (*out)[in.size()] = 0;
    p(std::wstring(*out), static_cast<void*>(*out));
}

class EnumString : public IEnumString {
public:
...
    IFACEMETHODIMP Next(ULONG celt, LPOLESTR *rgelt, ULONG *pceltFetched) {
        debugp p(__FUNCTION__);
        p(celt);
        HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

        ULONG i = 0;
        for (; i < celt && current < strings.size(); ++i, ++current) {
            p(i, current);
            CoCopyWString(strings[current], rgelt+i);
            p(static_cast<void*>(rgelt + i), static_cast<void*>(rgelt[i]));
        }

        if (celt > 1) {
            *pceltFetched = i;
        }
        if (i == celt) {
            hr = S_OK;
        }

        return hr;
    }
...
private:
    std::vector<std::wstring> strings;
    ULONG current = 0;
};
```

As shown, there's lots of debug prints, because attaching a debugger to MSSpellCheckingHost is quite an annoyance, and they yield the expected output of e.g.:

```
EnumString::Next
    1
    0 0
    CoCopyWString
        i-llu 0000000000000000
        i-llu 000001CC35682AE0
    ~CoCopyWString
    000001CC356A1F50 000001CC35682AE0
~EnumString::Next
```

...which shows the output pointer being set and the data pointed to is correct. And it works when [SupportedLanguages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869793.aspx) is called - that returns the correct value to the enumerator and the value is used so it couldn't have been null. But when [Suggest()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869788.aspx) is used, the results don't make it through.

All other functions that return structures allocated via `CoTaskMemAlloc` also work, so overall the host appears functional, except in that one case.

Comment: What do you mean by "leave the client's pointer null"? The client should pass a pointer to an array of pointers, which is filled in by `Next`. Is that what the client code does?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, yup, client is MS's own sample. It passes in the correct thing (boils down to a wchar_t**), but it remains null when `Next` returns. I can't even debug the path through because the MSSpellCheckingHost doesn't have debug symbols available. I did try to set any bit in the output just to see if I could fiddle with it, but nothing makes it through in that one call.

Comment: You must *always* assign `*pceltFetched`.  0 is a correct value for "there are no suggestions".

Comment: @HansPassant, you're right. I read the documentation to say that `pceltFetched` is only used if `celt > 1`, but it's actually if `celt > 1 || pceltFetched`. I would never have caught that. Post as real answer...

Comment: Well, check if it fixes the bug.  Once you get confirmation, you can post the answer as well as I can.

Comment: @HansPassant, I did confirm that it worked, 'cause I was about to post that the documentation said otherwise, but figured I'd test before claiming to know better...and I was in the wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out, the snippet

```
    if (celt > 1) {
        *pceltFetched = i;
    }
```

should instead be

```
    if (pceltFetched) {
        *pceltFetched = i;
    }
```